# Cardinality of continum

Tags: set-theory

We define for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ a set $\Phi(x)\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}$.

We call a subset S of $\mathbb{R}$ independent if $S\cap \Phi(S)=\emptyset$.

Prove that there is independent set of $\mathbb{R}$, where card(S)=cardinality of continum=$card(\mathbb{R})$.

In the effort to prove that i didn't find a way to begin. After i thought to choose a element from every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and define for that a set $\Phi(x)\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}$. In that moment i stucked.

Comment: What does $\Phi(S)$ mean? It seems like if you're referring to the image of $S$ under $\Phi$, then $\Phi(S) \subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$ while $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so the intersection doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is there another condition on $\Phi(x)$ that you forgot to mention? If $\Phi(x)=\mathbb R\setminus\{x\}$ for each $x$, then there is no independent set with more than one element.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm guessing that $\Phi(S)=\bigcup_{x\in S}\Phi(x)$.

Comment: The statement is true if you assume that $\Phi(x)$ is a **finite** set for each $x$.

Comment: First of all i believe tha @bof is right $\Phi(S)=\cup_{x\in S} \Phi(x)$. It's not mention that $\Phi(x)$ should be finite or infinite set. I don't understand how the statement is true if you assume $\Phi(x)$ is a finite set? By your idea i thought that to define $S=(0,1)$, which has $Card(S)=Card(\mathbb{R})$ and for every $x,y\in S$ with $x\neq y$ map to interval $I_{x} \neq I_{y}$.